# WPF: Create Image Button click only on non-transparent portion using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Okay guys, I am trying to make an image button with .png image but i need to make only Non-Transparent portion is a clickable using XAML.

i tried alot using custom image class but none of this tries worked for me.

Here is a sample of the png image i am using.

[image: Image1]

Here is a sample code of my image button in xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="Home1_Unlocked" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="611"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="541"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100,50,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Name="WholeButton" Background="Transparent">
                        <ui:MapObject x:Name="Home" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Resources/Game/map/but1_dim.png">
                            <!--<ui:MapObject.RenderTransformOrigin>
                                <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5"/>
                            </ui:MapObject.RenderTransformOrigin>
                            <ui:MapObject.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                            </ui:MapObject.RenderTransform>-->
                        </ui:MapObject>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <TextBlock Text="0 of 0 STARS" Style="{DynamicResource Riffic}" Margin="130,0,00,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="40">
                                <TextBlock.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"/>
                                </TextBlock.Effect>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Resources/Game/map/wmapenable.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Stretch="None"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Resources/Game/map/big1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,0,0,0" Stretch="None"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Home" Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Game/map/but1.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="WholeButton" Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.01" ScaleY="1.01" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="WholeButton" Property="RenderTransformOrigin">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and here is custom image class...

```
public class MapObject : Image
    {
        protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
        {
            var source = (BitmapSource)Source;

            // Get the pixel of the source that was hit
            var x = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X / ActualWidth * source.PixelWidth);
            var y = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y / ActualHeight * source.PixelHeight);

            // Copy the single pixel into a new byte array representing RGBA
            var pixel = new byte[4];
            source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, 4, 0);

            // Check the alpha (transparency) of the pixel
            // - threshold can be adjusted from 0 to 255
            if (pixel[3] < 10)
                return null;

            return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
        }
    }
```

Could abyone help me doing this?

Comment: If the image is just an icon, better use a Path element instead of Image.

Comment: Nope, its not an icon, i added the image to the question to be clarified

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to draw a vector based graphic. You can convert PNG to vector graphic as well, but this would require some rework and some good algorith (Adobe Ilustrator). Once it is a vector based graphic (not pixel based) you can convert it into a XAML resource (a drawing that consists of geometries). This would make it very easy to accomplish what you need.

Comment: All other options I can come up with are rather complex or suffer accuracy. E.g. use edge detection algorithm to draw a `Path` around the image. Or draw a rectangle around the image that aligns as close as possible with the image. The goal is to overlay the image to remove hit testing.

Comment: Using Vectors instead of png images not solving the issue.
I can do it by making my own custom button and use code-behinde button effects and other stuff instead of using XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I'd look into:

- confirming that the pixel detected is the one you think. It looks like you're aware of DPI scaling but even then it's easy to miss something (e.g. an inverted Y axis, incorrect mapping from WPF coordinates to pixel coordinates...).
- whether anything else is also handling the mouse click. Perhaps the hit test on the image works correctly, but the button behind is still handling the mouse click on the transparent areas?
- if you can't get it to work at the image level, you may be able to define a Geometry which covers the same area as your image, and do your hit testing against that geometry. Of course, if you have many images, this might not be an appropriate solution.
- consider whether WPF is the right tool for the job. WPF is primarily a User Interface framework. While you can definitely use it to do lower level graphics, using a Button means you will end up with a lot of UI functionality by default that you may not want: user being able to tab to select the button or use the keyboard to submit it, visual highlights, low frame rates (because all kind of events are taking place in the background that you don't really care about but use precious resources), etc. There may be some better suited tools for what you're trying to do. I'd suggest looking at game frameworks like [Unity](https://unity.com/) or [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/), both of which can be used with C# and will give you a lot of game-specific functionality out of the box, without all the baggage that a UI framework carries with it.

Comment: What i am seeking to do is can be done in WPF if i made my own custom button to handle of issue's i am facing right now and so on, Also i can handle standard or custom effects in code-behinde instead of Xaml one.